# Redefine function after change of coordinates (variables)

Tags: function-construction, variable

I wish to define functions of (possibly) several variables and then apply variable transformations in order to obtain a more comfortable expression. But I run into trouble because I need to redefine the function by calling the previous definition. So I guess here is where I run into trouble.

Here ist a little toy example:

```
f[{x_,y_}] := 2*x^2+4*x*y+y^2;
R[{x_,y_}] := {x,y-2*x};
```

Now I would like to redefine f as the composition of f and R. The "obvious" method

```
f[{x_,y_}] := Composition[f,R][{x,y}];
```

does not work since this leads to an infinite iteration process. So I would like to find a way to first evaluate the composition and then redefine f[{x_,y_}] to be the resulting expression. Can anybody help me out here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good example of when you can use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) for defining a function, or rather when it's a good idea to *not* use [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).  Since you want to assign the *evaluated* rhs of the composition to `f` (and the result has a closed form), instead of redoing the composition each time the new `f` is called (leading to the infinite recursion), you can directly assign the result of the composition.

```
f[{x_, y_}] := 2*x^2 + 4*x*y + y^2
R[{x_, y_}] := {x, y - 2*x}
f[{x_, y_}] = f@*R@{x, y} (*@* is the infix notation for Composition*)
f[{A,B}]
```

> 2 x^2 + 4 x (-2 x + y) + (-2 x + y)^2
>
> 2 A^2 + 4 A (-2 A + B) + (-2 A + B)^2

It even has the right [`DownValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html).

```
DownValues@f
```

> {HoldPattern[f[{x_, y_}]] :> 2 x^2 + 4 x (-2 x + y) + (-2 x + y)^2}

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is pretty much what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Since your definition of `R`

```
f[{x_, y_}] := 2*x^2 + 4*x*y + y^2;
R[{x_, y_}] := {x, y - 2*x};
```

returns a list of two elements, it has the correct structure to serve as input to `f`.
So you can simply do

```
f[R[{A, B}]]
```

> 2 A^2 + 4 A (-2 A + B) + (-2 A + B)^2

to obtain `f` evaluated on `R`, evaluated on arbitrary input `{A,B}`.

**EDIT**

If you want to redefine `f`, then simply save the new entry as

```
f[{A_,B_}] = f[R[{A, B}]];
```

Now, whenever you call `f[{x,y}]` the new definition is going to be invoked.

Comment: Yes, but my intention is do redefine f as the composition of f and R. The reason being that I will probably have to perform a series of such coordinate changes so I don't want to use new functions everytime.

Comment: @Teddyboer see the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

```
f[{x_, y_}] := 2*x^2 + 4*x*y + y^2;
R[{x_, y_}] := {x, y - 2*x};

f[{x_, y_}] := Evaluate@Composition[f, R][{x, y}]

f[{A, B}]

(* 2 A^2 + 4 A (-2 A + B) + (-2 A + B)^2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This also works pretty well. I assume that "Evaluate@" tells the compiler to first evaluate the rhs before everything else?

Comment: Yes, so the rhs no longer refers to `f`, which avoids the infinite recursion.